# PowerShell script to get employee number from list of emails

Tags: active-directory

I have a list of email addresses in a CSV file from which I would like to get the employee number against each row exported into a new CSV file.  I tried with a powershell script but am struggling a bit and was wondering if somebody could point me in the right direction.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Import-Csv 'C:\ps\EmailIDIFS.csv' | ForEach {
Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq '$($_email)'" -Properties Name, 
emailAddress, SAMAccountName, employeeNumber | `
Select Name, emailAddress, SamAccountName, employeeNumber | `
Export-CSV 'C:\ps\ADResults.csv' -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Unfortunately when I run this I get the following error:

> Get-ADUser : The search filter cannot be recognized At
>   C:\Users\jfoote\Nextcloud\Local\scripts\ADEmployeeNumber.ps1:3 char:1
>   + Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq '$($_email)'" -Properties Name,  ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8254,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're just missing a period on this line:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq '$($_email)'" -Properties Name, emailAddress, SAMAccountName, employeeNumber
```

The `$_email` should probably be `$_.email` (assuming you have a heading called "email" in your CSV file).

Note that an email address can be used in the `Identity` parameter as well, which is the default parameter. So you could simplify it like this:

```
Get-ADUser $_.email -Properties Name, emailAddress, SAMAccountName, employeeNumber
```

The effect is exactly the same. It's just easier to read.